# unattended-upgrade message "Could not figure out development release: Distribution data outdated."

Tags: apt, package-management

**EDIT:  This error persists after running `apt update`.**

So we have an AWS EC2 instance running 22.04 LTS.  It's been powered off for a while, so after booting I wanted to grab **just the security-related package updates**.  The way to do that documented elsewhere on SO/askubuntu is running `unattended-upgrade` by hand, which makes sense.  Unfortunately, I'm getting a weird message:

```shell
$ sudo unattended-upgrade -v
Could not figure out development release: Distribution data outdated. Please check for an update for distro-info-data. See /usr/share/doc/distro-info-data/README.Debian for details.
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=jammy, o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=jammy-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=jammy-infra-security
Initial blacklist:
Initial whitelist (not strict):
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

So I double-check that the proper repos are being checked; these are untouched from the 22.04 LTS image that Canonical published on AWS:

```shell
$ grep ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
deb http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
deb http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
deb http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
deb http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
```

That part looks normal (the `ec2.archive` stuff is all mirrors managed by Canonical).  Then I threw the error at google and somebody else had the same problem a year ago over at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2480465 but that concludes with

```
This is LP#1993667, which will be fixed by distro-info-data 0.52ubuntu0.2 once that is fully released.
```

Looking at https://launchpad.net/bugs/1993667 it says that a fix was indeed released to jammy as 0.52ubuntu0.2 last year.  Checking what we have locally...

```shell
$ apt policy distro-info-data
distro-info-data:
  Installed: 0.52ubuntu0.4
  Candidate: 0.52ubuntu0.4
  Version table:
 *** 0.52ubuntu0.4 500
        500 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.52ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
     0.52 500
        500 http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

...we already have that fix and more.

So, what is `unattended-upgrade` complaining about on an LTS release?  The `README.Debian` file it refers to gives very generic advice to make sure the updates repo is in sources.list, which it already is.

Comment: What happens if you just do a `sudo apt update`?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Standard `update/upgrade` also grabs all the non-security changes, which is not what I want at this time.  Apparently that gets a downvote on this site?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. Just wondered why you'd run unattended upgrades manually, which your comment explains. However, `sudo apt update` by itself, which is what I suggested, won't upgrade anything. It just updates the package lists. I did not suggest an `upgrade`.

Comment: Correct, running just `update` fetches package information, but does not change the results of the `distro-info` output if re-run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade just that one package `distro-info-data`, as in: `sudo apt install --only-upgrade distro-info-data`.

I encountered this too in a 22.04 server setup similar to yours (keeps up only with security updates). Turns out the warning message is exactly what it says, that is, we just needed to check for an update to `distro-info-data` and install it if available.

The issue, if you could call it that, was that the necessary update was only published in [version `0.52ubuntu0.5` on Oct 24](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/distro-info-data/0.52ubuntu0.5), after this question was asked, and two weeks or so after the warning started appearing in servers like yours and mine.

Comment: Yep, I looked through the script source after giving up on getting answers, and it turns out that `unattended-upgrades` insists on trying to figure out if you're running a "devel" distro even when the release is specifically tagged as LTS.  \*eyeroll\*  Once the "devel" tag moves to a new distro, all the existing LTS installations start complaining because, you know, they might suddenly be development mode and can't figure it out.  Sigh.